# collection-repeat inside ion-scroll is cutting out the last item in the list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use ionic for my mobile app. I have a Directory with a list of employees. It works fine except that the last employee name gets cut or is not visible.
I use collections-repeat inside ion-scroll. Above this I filter directive. The filter directive should not be scrollable.

I tried setting bottom:50px for the last item in the list, it brings up the last item, but writes over the item above it.

Any suggestions on how to fi this would be break

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
        <filters on-query-change="onQueryChange()" class="filter-directive"></filters>
        <hr class="hline">

        <ion-scroll class="scroll-length">
            <div 
                 collection-repeat="contact in contacts track by contact.id"
                 item-width="100%"
                 item-height="getHeight(contact)"
                 ng-show="(contact.fullName || contact.isDivider)>
                <div id="company-directory-item-divider"
                     class="item item-divider fw-semibold dark"
                     ng-if="contact.isDivider">
                     {{contact.letter}}
                </div>
                <div 
                     class="item item-icon-right tn-nav-item"
                     ng-click="gotoEmployeeInfo(contact)"
                     ng-if="contact.fullName">
                    <span ng-bind-html="contact.fullName"></span>
                    <div class="tn-nav-item-subtitle dark"> {{contact.workShortLocDesc}}</div>
                    <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        <ion-scroll>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: what about `.scroll-length{margin-bottom:50px!important;}`

Comment: @gerdi I tried the option margin-bottom:50px!important & -bottom:50px!important in scroll-length. both dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the div with collection repeat should be the first element inside ion-content for this to work:

So this is how I finally fixed it:

- Got rid of ion-scoll
- made ion-content  scrollable
- Put the *filter directive* and *hline* between ion-header and ion-content and set it to position absolute (along with some margin top styling)
- styled ion-content with margin-top to bring it lower (so as not to write over the filter)
  This worked.